# Runtime Error: out of gas when calling method on contract

Tags: truffle, testrpc

I am using Truffle Framework and TestRPC. I have the following method on my contract:

```
function sendEmr(address receiver, string universalPatientId, string firstName, string lastName, string url) returns(bool val){

    emrRecords[receiver].universalPatientId = universalPatientId;
    emrRecords[receiver].firstName = firstName;
    emrRecords[receiver].lastName = lastName;
    emrRecords[receiver].url = url;

    EMRTransfer(msg.sender, receiver, universalPatientId, firstName, lastName, url);

    return true;
}
```

When I execute this method from my DAPP; I am receiving the following error in TESTRPC:

```
eth_accounts
eth_call
eth_call
eth_sendTransaction

  Transaction: 0xe212676e7b4b906d01932d7d2b7de9872d4e2a46e7730fee22e7488756f00d08
  Gas usage: 0x015f90
  Block Number: 0x07
  Block Time: Thu Jun 22 2017 11:36:03 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
  Runtime Error: out of gas
```

What should I do to handle this situation. Thank you very much!

Comment: are you passing very long strings in function arguments? if yes then try passing small strings to see if that works.

Comment: @Sanchit - I tried just sending in 'A', 'B', 'C' for the arguments, still same error.  Since I am just using this as experimental; is there a way to turn off the gas limit or is this not a possibility?

Comment: yes, while starting testrpc, give argument --gasPrice and give your Gas value.

For e.g. - "testrpc --gasPrice 20000"

Comment: Also, do you have a lot of functions in a single contract? if yes then I recommend breaking them into multiple contracts.

Comment: was that of any help?

Comment: @Sanchit - I removed the firstName and lastName parameters and that worked; I was able to perform my operation without running out of gas, so that did help!  Thanks for that tip!   I still am wondering though; as I would like to pass this information to the blockchain; how can I properly provide more gas in order to do what I need?

Answer (score 4):

I ended up resolving this by passing in more gas when calling the contract's method:

For example:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({gas: <some large number>}) or someContract.someMethod(arg1, arg2, {gas: <some large number>}).
```

So in my case I did this:

```
meta.sendEmr(receiver, universalPatientId, firstName, url, {from: account, gas: 1000000});
```